QScrollArea doesn't make Scroll Bars
I want to create a program that displays a button in the Scroll Area.
However, even if I put a lot of buttons, the Scroll Bar is not created in the Scroll Area and the buttons are only cut off.
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui

class UI_MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1024, 768)

        icon_x = 10
        icon_y = 60
        icon_button_width = 60
        icon_button_height = 60
        icon_label_width = 60
        icon_label_height = 20

        tier_x = 0
        tier_y = 40
        tier_button_width = 50
        tier_button_height = 50

        icons_folder = '.\\c_icons\\champ_icons'
        icon_files = os.listdir(icons_folder)
        icon_path = []
        for icon_file in icon_files:
            icon_path.append(os.path.join(icons_folder, icon_file))
        icon_path.sort()

        tier_icon_folder = '.\\c_icons\\tier_icons'
        tier_icon_files = os.listdir(tier_icon_folder)
        tier_icon_path = []
        for tier_icon_file in tier_icon_files:
            tier_icon_path.append(os.path.join(tier_icon_folder, tier_icon_file))

        tier_folder = '.\\c_prop'
        tier_files = os.listdir(tier_folder)
        tier_path = []
        for tier_file in tier_files:
            tier_path.append(os.path.join(tier_folder, tier_file))
        tier_f = pd.read_excel(str(tier_path)[2:-2], header=None, index_col=None)

        scroll_area_1 = QScrollArea(self)
        scroll_area_1.setGeometry(120, 100, 300, 600)
        scroll_area_1.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll_content_1 = QWidget()
        scroll_area_1.setWidget(scroll_content_1)
        scroll_area_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: #201F22;"
                                    "border-width: 0px;"
                                    "border-radius: 15px;")

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(scroll_content_1)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(10, 10, 280, 40)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: #2B2B30;"
                                    "border-width: 0px;"
                                    "border-radius: 3px;")
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.filterButtons)
        self.lineEdit.setMaximumHeight(40)

        self.icon_buttons = []
        self.icon_labels = []
        for j in range(icon_path.__len__()):
            button = QPushButton(scroll_content_1)
            button.setIcon(QIcon(icon_path[j]))
            button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(icon_button_width, icon_button_height))
            button.setGeometry(icon_x, icon_y, icon_button_width, icon_button_height)
            button.setObjectName(f"Icon_{str(icon_files[j][:-4])}")
            button.setText("")  # 버튼 텍스트 제거
            self.icon_buttons.append(button)

            label = QLabel(f"Label {j + 1}", scroll_content_1)
            label.setText(icon_files[j][:-4])
            label.setObjectName(f"Label {j + 1}")
            if len(icon_files[j][:-4]) > 3:
                label.setText((str(icon_files[j][:3]) + "..."))
            label.setGeometry(icon_x, icon_y + 60, icon_label_width, icon_label_height)
            label.setStyleSheet("color: #9E9EAF;")
            self.icon_labels.append(label)
            if j % 4 == 3:
                icon_x = 10
                icon_y += 100
            else:
                icon_x += 70
    def filterButtons(self, text):
        text = text.replace(" ", "")
        x = 10
        y = 50
        i = 0
        for button, label in zip(self.icon_buttons, self.icon_labels):
            if text not in button.objectName():
                button.hide()
                label.hide()
                button.setDisabled(True)
                label.setDisabled(True)
            else:
                button.show()
                label.show()
                button.setEnabled(True)
                label.setEnabled(True)
                button.setGeometry(x, y, 60, 60)
                label.setGeometry(x, y + 60, 60, 20)
                if (i + 1) % 4 == 0:
                    y += 80
                    x = 10
                else:
                    x += 70
                i += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = UI_MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

In this code, even if I set Alwayson with the setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy function, the scrollbar is visible but cannot be manipulated.
Also, when using Grid Layout, I cannot adjust the size of each object to the desired pixel, so I don't want to do that.
Is there any way to create a scrollbar without using the setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy function and GridLayout?

Like it or not, layouts are the correct solution. Use e.g. min/max sizes, spacers and margins to control the geometry of the widgets within the layout.
